# How to bind an event of jquery with html5 kinetic shape?

Tags: jquery, html, kineticjs

I have a html 5 canvas where i have a polygon . I want to bind this polygon with jquery. but i am not getting how to do it.

Polygon:

```
    var poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    points: [37,224,250,296,388,239,391,336,250,416,151,374,150,368,127,360,127,364,37,325],
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    name: 'poly',
    draggable: false,
    id:'skirt'
    });
```

Jquery:

```
    $('what to put here?').droppable({
     function body..................
    });
```

Hope any one can help or correct me here...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things drawn on a canvas are not part of the DOM tree (only the canvas itself is) so you cannot bind any events to them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , please tell me is it possible to use ajax with kinetic.js events ?

Comment: yes ajax is possible ... node.on('click', function(){ ajax goes here }); You can just use jquery and kineticjs together, they are namespaced so they won't interfere with each other.